# What is the difference between button and span when invoke focus?

Tags: javascript, html, button

HTML code fragment:

```
<div contenteditable='true' id="txt">123<b>456</b>789</div> 
<button onclick="get()">Click Me</button> 
<span onclick="get()">Click Me</span> 
<script>   
  function get(){
      document.getElementById('txt').focus()
  }
</script>
```

> - Click the node named `txt`, set the cursor before `7`,and then click Button.
>     Watch the div's cursor position.
> - Click the node named `txt`, set the cursor before `7`,and then click Span.
>     Watch the div's cursor position

Compare the div's cursor position,
You will find that the `Button` click event does not change the div's original cursor position.
But the `Span` click event does.

That is really weird, so what is happening here?
(My test is based on WebKit browsers.)

Comment: `txt.focus()` is very limited to some browsers so start using `document.getElementById('txt').focus()`

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is the same in Firefox.

I'll go out on a limb and speculate that clicking on the span will lead to the cursor being moved to where you clicked in the span, meaning that its position inside the div is now lost.  Movig the focus back to the div will place it at the default location (the beginning).  Clicking on the button won't lead to the cursor being moved, since a button cannot accomodate a cursor; so your cursor has remained at the position in the div all along.

The cursor is the one of the html document, also used to select text, for instance; or shown in Firefox if you turn caret browsing on.  Now if you use a control (textbox, or textarea) instead of a div with `contenteditable=true`, the behaviour will be as you expected (no difference between clicking the span or the button), because the control manages its own cursor (to test this, just replace the div by a `textarea`).

Comment: Well, I do not know how browsers implement the button.But I made a few test and found that we can get the same result by binding the span's click Event on the mousedown event and invoking e.preventDefault() in the mousedown event to avoid the div's cursor lost.

Comment: actually,i am quite confused about cursor and focus,especially on button.

Comment: Really? In my Firefox the cursor just disappears. :/

Answer (score 0):

One note regarding to the accessibility of what you're doing,  tags aren't considered a "clickable" asset like a button is.  So when it comes to the keyboard-only access of the controls that you're creating, the  tag wouldn't necessarily work universally for those that don't navigate through page content with a mouse and rely upon their keyboard.